# strftime adding +1 day also removes 5 minutes

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, strtotime

Somehow, using strtotime and adding "+1 day" not only adds the day, but also removes 5 minutes.

In the following example I expect '2013-10-02 08:15:00', but get '2013-10-02 08:10:00':

```
$myDate = '2013-10-01 08:15:00';
$newDate = strtotime($myDate . ' +1 day');
$newDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:00", $newDate);
debug($newDate);

//'2013-10-02 08:10:00'
```

BUT - if I use `date()` instead of `strftime()`, it works fine

```
$myDate = '2013-10-01 08:15:00';
$newDate = strtotime($myDate . ' +1 day');
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $newDate);
debug($newDate);

//'2013-10-02 08:15:00'
```

Comment: On your system only. There must be some other problem, this can't be the full code, is it?

Comment: Woops spoke too soon. Happens with strftime function

Comment: lol %m is for month not minute http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Comment: @Prashank - you're right - I thought it didn't work with both, but it's only w/ `strftime`.  That helps at least - I have a workaround.  Will still accept any answer that explains why or how to work it w/ strftime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed a capital M instead of m.

Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

```
$myDate = '2013-10-01 08:15:00';
$newDate = strtotime($myDate . ' +1 day');
$newDate = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00", $newDate);
debug($newDate);
```

Comment: Voila - sometimes it's the stupidest little things :)  Thanks.